# setInterval function not working

Tags: javascript

I seem to not be able to call the `setInterval` function like this:

```
this.timerHandler = setInterval(function(this.myTimerFunction){},1000)
```

It seems that if I make a global function and call that, the code works perfectly but it seems that calling a function locally using `this`, it won't work. I have tried calling `this.myTimerFunction` just before this line of code and it actually executes the code and works perfect, it's just that it seems it does not want to execute the function from a timer handler.

Any suggestions to try and fix this? `this.myTimerFunction` is a prototype function btw.

Comment: Your syntax is invalid for starters. The call goes inside the function body, not in the parameter list. Then you need to invoke the function. Finally, you need to make sure `this` is what you intend for it to be,.

Comment: what do you expect "timerHandler" to be a property of ?

Comment: [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711 under "the this variable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setInterval` takes a function and an interval.

`function(this.myTimerFunction){}`

should just be:

`this.myTimerFunction`
or
`this.myTimerFunction.bind(this)`

You may not need the bind if the context doesn't matter.

Comment: Thankyou so much!! I had no idea that when you call a function with setInterval, it run the function from the global scope. Again thanks, seems to work. :)

Answer (score 1):

the syntax is wrong, you also have to take into account the context

```
var that=this; //save context

this.timerHandler = setInterval(function(){ //You can not use "this." like parameter
   that.myTimerFunction(params); 
},1000)
```

if you don't need send parameters in your function you can use

```
this.timerHandler = setInterval(this.myTimerFunction,1000);
```

Comment: Thanks. I found out that I did not bind the context as I do not want to call the function from the global scope. Thanks for telling me about the context.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.timerHandler = setInterval(this.myTimerFunction, 1000);
```

Comment: I assume he doesn't want this to be window in myTimerFunction and therefore tries to pass a closure to setTimeout

Comment: Thanks. I found out that I did not bind the context as I do not want to call the function from the global scope.